# java program to read specific data

Tags: java, excel

I need java code to read data for specific column from excel sheet. – (lo number, line, voucher no, stloc , quantity ,activity.)
These set of values for a particular column will be used for sql query (jdbc-odbc connection done).
The output for the query will be matched with a column in this sheet (this part ll be done later)
Kindly help.
[sample excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Akgxtpfo7Zs1dE1ERWFsR0dFRzVvaTZNMlpXcEloemc)

Comment: You can use apache poi for working with excel sheets. It's not tough to code with that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package excelfilereading;

/**
 *
 * @author vkantiya
 */
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//
// An excel file name. You can create a file name with a full
// path information.
//
        String filename = "FirstExcel.xls";


// Create an ArrayList to store the data read from excel sheet.
//
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
//
// Create a FileInputStream that will be use to read the
// excel file.
//
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

//
// Create an excel workbook from the file system.
//
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
//
// Get the first sheet on the workbook.
//
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//
// When we have a sheet object in hand we can iterator on
// each sheet's rows and on each row's cells. We store the
// data read on an ArrayList so that we can printed the
// content of the excel to the console.
//
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }

                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }

        showExelData(sheetData);
    }

    private static void showExelData(List sheetData) {
//
// Iterates the data and print it out to the console.
//
        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) list.get(j);
                System.out.print(
                        cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                if (j < list.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) - the Java API for Microsoft Documents.

It covers

- Excel (SS=HSSF+XSSF)
- Word (HWPF+XWPF)
- PowerPoint (HSLF+XSLF)
- OpenXML4J (OOXML)
- OLE2 Filesystem (POIFS)
- OLE2 Document Props (HPSF)
- Outlook (HSMF)
- Visio (HDGF) TNEF (HMEF)
- Publisher (HPBF)

Comment: There's also jxl. Discussion of the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763624/jexcelapi-vs-apache-poi-which-is-better